# How to implement such a formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

[image: Example]

In my example above I have the following:

1. Column A: Products (never duplicated) - you can see listed 5 elements (the products can vary in number - I would like a formula to work for a general case of numbers);
2. `B1`: always a constant;
3. Column E: The products from column A, listed below each other, their appearance multiplied by `B1`, i.e. 3 times "Cereal", 3 times "Milk" etc. one after another.

My question is as follows: How can I automate (using only formulas) column E? (so if I were to change column A and `B1`, E then gets updated with the new values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` function:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/$B$1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  This is what I needed :)

Comment: @Voici'sVoices don't forget to accept the answer then